# How to set up a GTM tag that states that the current page should have the same source as the previous page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

A while back we notice that our payment provider was changing the source every people land on our confirmation page, which resulted in the referral channel to take most of the conversion credit.

We add the payment server to our referral exclusion list and it worked for a while.

Now we have noticed that the direct channel is taking the credit for the conversion. Until we can figure out what is causing this issue, we decided that it would best to set up a GTM tag so that whenever a user lands on the booking confirmation page, the page has to have the same source as the previous page.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I am not sure this is even possible. Changing campaign information starts a new session, so changing it back would conceivably start just a session more. Also in the end attribution happens on the GA server and there is no back channel to get the attribution information in realtime (for any realistic scenario). Much better to find and fix the problem than looking for a workaround.

Comment: But of course for an approximation you could catch campaign parameters on the landing page, write them to a cookie and then overwrite the source/medium/campaignName fields with values from the cookie in subsequent pageviews. Not really a good idea, but somebody is bound to mention it so I might do it first.